# Controlling movement of vehicle agents on GIS roads

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I am developing an anylogic simulation with GIS library. I have created vehicle as a population of agents on the GIS map. How can I use the roads of the gis map similar to the roads of Road Library? in order to control car movements on GIS map roads. I have also tried using shape files for roads to convert gis routes into Roads. But the shape file includes other areas too apart from just the main roads I want. Kindly guide If anyone has expertise over GIS Library Anylogic.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a shapefile yourself with what you need using arcGIS (it will not be easy and will require A LOT of work)
2. Creat a .osm or .pbf file where you can control the routing of cars yourself instead of relying in an external server that controls your routes (also arcGIS required and A LOT of work)

What you are asking is not easy and I have the feeling you are looking for an easy solution. And I think points 1 and 2 are necessary, but depending on what you want point 2 may be enough.

Nevertheless, no matter what you do, you will never have the same behavior as the road traffic library unless you create yourself the map with the traffic library itself (again an immense amount of work if you have a lot of routes). You can nevertheless use an image of the map you are interested in, and put the roads from the traffic library where you need them.

you CANNOT put roads from the traffic library on a GIS map.

Comment: Thanks Felipe for clarifying the concepts :)